# window 8 installation with already using dual boot window 7 and ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, installation, windows-8, boot-partition

i am already using windows7 and ubuntu as a dual boot with EasyBCD software. now i have a another seperate drive for windows 8 installation. ( i try to directly installation in different drive but when PC is restart only window 7 and 8 is showing , no option for ubuntu ) Tell me the best way to install win 8 and also keep together with ubuntu and win 7 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hurry....!! i successfully install 3 OS in my laptop. 
We require 3 different partitions and EasyBCD software that is free available. Lets try:-

(1) install your PRIMARY OS like windows XP,7,8 with and also install EasyBCD for 
smart boot loading.

(2) Now in another partiton install ubuntu with dual booting concept and use "ext4"  partition

(3) use EasyBCD to set the booting options between 2 os.

(4) now in another partitions that is NTFS install windows 8 and " after successfully installation , in search open 'msconfig' file , there is a boot option , make the window 7 as a primary and default option and restart the pc.

now 3 OS are available for selection and work upon it. 
enjoy.......