# Problems with Windows 8 Installation

Tags: windows, 64-bit, samsung, ultrabook

I've followed all the instructions and when I get to dual screen boot I choose Ubuntu and I receive a message:
1. Insert Windows Installation Disc and restart.
2. Choose Language end then press next.
3. Preess restore device.

If you don't have this disc get in touch with system administrator  or the manufacturer.

Info: There's a file missing or it contained an error which is preventing from booting the OS.

Enter= OS selection                  Esc UEFI configuration

Please help me on what to do to complete the installation.
Thanks

Comment: Read this:-

http://askubuntu.com/questions/256022/window-8-installation-with-already-using-dual-boot-window-7-and-ubuntu

Comment: Which instructions did you follow? What did you try to accomplish? Sounds to me like you have a machine that is setup for UEFI booting without compatibility support and installed Windows 8 in MBR mode or the other way around. It's also possible that BCD data is corrupt and it would just require reconfiguration from within Windows, but we need more information from you to not cause more damage than whan has already been done.

Comment: I've followed this instructions http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-with-windows And Im trying to install ubuntu on my computer.What more information do you needd???

Answer (score -2):

First start the ubuntu and update you GRUB(booting in ubuntu) by running the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

and visit:-
http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

Try to install window8 in different partition and run type "msconfig" -> select boot option and manage your boot list of window8 or ubuntu .

You can also try easyBCD software for booting.

Comment: It's the Windows boot manager that gives the error message, doing that pesky boot repair is superfluous and will probably make things worse unless Windows boot manager is bypassed and the Windows loader for BIOS or UEFI is called directly, but I'd rather fix the issue than to work around it.

Comment: How can I try your instructions if I cant acces ubuntu?

Comment: you can make a bootable disk , download from here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair and boot initially.